# How to change a repo during push to server?

Tags: git, tfs, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I have an utility for grabbing some code metrics from solution. I want to keep the result of this utility in the git repository, like a file in the repository root folder; this should help me compare solution states.

So, the workflow is local commit -> push -> utility run -> remote commit. Is that possible?

What are alternatives if my idea is incorrect? Keep utility generated files in the \\fileshare\master\commitHashUtilityResult.xml? I'm interested in git and tfs repositories.

Comment: Sounds possible, but the result would be a bit infuriating as a developer. You'd have to create a new commit on the branch on the server, which means that my local repo would be out of sync almost as soon as I pushed to the server, and every other commit in the git history would be one of these utility files.

Comment: Seems like good scenario for using `git-notes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One "hack" would be to consider adding to a commit (with a post-receive hook) some  notes (as commented with [`git notes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes)).

But generally, "collecting some metrics" is delegated to a third-party tool, which will store said metrics in an external referential (with a link back to the Git commit)

Typically, you would use [SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/), which can be installed for free, in order to store those metrics and easily compare their evolution over time.